# how to get data multiply times using SSR in nextjs

Tags: server-side-rendering, next.js13

im working on my tutorial project with next js. im trying to create weather app using OpenWeatherMap API. My problem is that i cant get data multiply times using SSR, but if i dont use SSR i always get a promise please help me.

This is a method cod which fetches data

```
import { API_KEY, BASE_API_URL } from "@/constants";
export class weather {
private baseURL: string = BASE_API_URL;
private keyAPI: string = API_KEY;
constructor() {}
public async getWeather(location: string) {
try {
const response = await fetch(
`${BASE_API_URL}q=${location}&appid=${API_KEY}`
);
if (!response.ok) {
throw new Error(`Failed to fetch weather data for ${location}`);
}
const json = await response.json();
return json;
} catch (error) {
console.error("Error fetching weather data:", error);
throw error; // Re-throw the error to handle it elsewhere if needed
}
}
}
```

this is home page which receives this data:

```
// HOME PAGE 

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
// style
import s from "@/styles/Home.module.scss"
// modules 
import { weather } from '@/modules/weather'
//components
import WeatherCityCard from '@/components/weatherCityCard'
// ts interfaces
interface TempWeather {
  data: any;
}

const Index = ({ data }: TempWeather) => {
 
  return (
    <>
    <WeatherCityCard data={data}/>
    </>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  try {
    // init
    const getData = new weather();
    const localWeather = await getData.getWeather('london');
    console.log(localWeather)
    
    return { props: { data: localWeather } };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching weather data:', error);
    return { props: { data: null } }; // Handle error gracefully
  }
}

export default Index;
```

i expect that i will have a redux storage which will keep all user favourite cities and then i should get all data from this cities and create as many components as it need